# Using unordered_multimap with a struct data type

Tags: c++

I need to define an unordered multimap which holds a key of type int and a value of type "nod".

Nod.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

struct nod {
    int stare[100], pathManhattan, depth;
    nod* nodParinte;
    char actiune;

    nod();
    void Citire(int n);
    void Init();
};
```

Nod.cpp

```
#include "Nod.h"
#include "ConsoleApplication1.cpp"

nod::nod()
{
    pathManhattan = 0;
    depth = 0;
    nodParinte = NULL;
}

void nod::Citire(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> stare[i];
    }
}

void nod::Init()
{
    theExplored.insert({ pathManhattan + depth, this });
}
```

The problems is the Init function. I don't know how to make it work.
ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Nod.h"

std::unordered_multimap<int, nod> theExplored;
std::unordered_multimap<int, nod> theFrontier;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In my mind it should work, because every nod would have an init function which inserts the node it is used on in theExplored, but I think I might not understood unordered_multimap correctly.

Is my logic flawed? If so, how should I create a Hash table (AFAIK unordered_multimap is basically a hash table) with the key int and the value of type nod?

Also, how can I make a function in the struct so that node gets inserted into the hash table?

Thanks.

Comment: In C++, pointers and objects are different things. Did you look at the error message?

Comment: `this` isn't a `nod`, it's a `nod *`

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes. I've tried with "nod" instead of "this" and it still didn't work.

Comment: Why are you *#including* a `.cpp` file? You should only be *#including* `.h` files

Comment: @Galik that's how I thought I would be able to access theFrontier from consoleapplication1.cpp. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a header file for the *map* definitions in your application source `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`. You can't just *#include* the source code as that will give you multiple definitions of your *maps*.

You can do this, create `ConsoleApplication1.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Nod.h"

extern std::unordered_multimap<int, nod> theExplored;
extern std::unordered_multimap<int, nod> theFrontier;
```

Notice the `extern` keyword. This means the code is just a *declaration* that the actual *maps* are *defined* elsewhere in the program (in an external file).

Of course your *definitions* are in `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`.

Now you can change your line `#include "ConsoleApplication1.cpp"` to `#include "ConsoleApplication1.h"` and that should solve your structural issue.